# Issue on Smooth Toggle Sliding (Up)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slide, slidetoggle

Can you please take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/52VtD/4340/) and let me know why I am not able to have a smooth slide up in my layout? I mean there is a jump when the slide catches the inner well(.login).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row top">
        <div class="well well-sm col-md-2 col-md-offset-10"><a id="login">Login</a> | Register <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign pull-right"></i>
           <div class="well login"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$("#login").click(function () {
    $(".login").slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

and the CSS is :

```
.login {
    display:none;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is caused by a min-height style in the bootstrap.css.  The min height is keeping the well from collapsing past 20px.  When the well expands it actually immediately displays a height of 20px. However, this is odd behavior is really only noticeable while its collapsing.

```
.well {
  min-height: 20px;  <--- THIS STYLE
  padding: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: @well-bg;
  border: 1px solid @well-border;
  border-radius: @border-radius-base;
  .box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05));
  blockquote {
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  }
}
```

You can specify the min-height with a more specific selector or applying a class to the well.

I simply applied a more specific selector to the well so it overrides the selector from the BootStrap.css.

```
div .well
{
 min-height:initial;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ej72d/

While that works, I suggest applying another class to the well div called wellNoMinHeight

```
.well.wellNoMinHeight
{
 min-height:initial;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TM2J3/

Comment: Thanks cgatian , that was perfect explanation!

Comment: Glad to be of help.  I like the CSS3 animations going on there, really hot.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that it is trying to slide down the div, however the div is awkwardly shaped (because of the well class).  Here is my solution, using jquery animate instead of slidetoggle

http://jsfiddle.net/pmalbu/52VtD/4344/

Here is the JavaScript I used:

```
var flip = 0;

$("#login").click(function () {
    if (flip++ % 2 === 0) {
        $( ".login" ).animate({
            'display': 'block',
            'margin-top': "20px"
        }, 300 );
        $( ".login" ).show(200); 
    }
    else {
        $( ".login" ).hide(200);
        $( ".login" ).animate({
            'display': 'block',
            'margin-top': "0"
        }, 300 ); 
    }
});
```